# How can I change the debug-level and format for the Quart (i.e. hypercorn) logger?

Tags: python, logging, quart, hypercorn

I'm trying to set the `level` and `format` for the loggers used by the Quart module the way I did it successfully for other 'foreign' loggers:

- by running `basicConfig` and implicitly setting up the root-logger or later
- by running `logging.getLogger("urllib3.connectionpool").setLevel(logging.INFO)` to get
  and modify an existing logger

However those approaches don't work for the loggers spawned by Quart. Neither are those affected by `basicConfig` nor can I set the level. Output will always look like this:

```
[2023-07-28 16:17:12 +0200] [1254610] [INFO] Running on http://0.0.0.0:5432 (CTRL + C to quit)
```

Setting breakpoints in `logging/__init__.py` let the program break on log messages by `hypercorn.error` (so it seems to use the same module), but setting the level like this

```
logging.getLogger("hypercorn.error").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

doesn't have any effect.

The [doc](https://quart.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/how_to_guides/logging.html) says I should use `dictConfig`, so I've added

```
dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'loggers': {
        'quart.app': {'level': 'ERROR'},
        'hypercorn.error': {'level': 'ERROR'},
    },
})
```

.. no effect

I found https://github.com/pgjones/hypercorn/issues/120, and tried

```
logger = logging.getLogger("hypercorn.error")
logger.addHandler(my_own_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logger.propagate = False
```

but also without effect.

What else can I try?